# Update content of BLOB column data in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, sql-update, cql

I have a table in Cassandra, in which one column is a BLOB.
I wish to update only some values in that blob. Is that possible ?
Example : 
String form of BLOB is let's say: 
*{"name":"ABC","rollNum": "1234"}*

I want to make it as : 
*{"name":"ABC","rollNum": "1333"}* with an CQL update query.

Originally this column gets update from my JAVA code where I send byte[] to be inserted in this BLOB column.
Now, I want to update just some fields without doing any type of select on this row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in general.

Cassandra as any other database does not know how to interpret your blob. You will

- need to read, parse, update and save your blob again
- use a map instead
- use single fields - which will give the most performance

Apart from that, updates like you want to do can be archived in document databases like MongoDB.